# How to auto open react DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I have the following code

```
      case 'date':
    if (Modernizr.touchevents && Modernizr.inputtypes && Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
      element = (
        <input
          type='date'
          id={this.props.id}
          name={this.props.name}
          onChange={arg => this.changeValue(moment(arg && arg.currentTarget ? arg.currentTarget.value : arg))}
          onBlur={arg => this.blurValue(moment(arg && arg.currentTarget ? arg.currentTarget.value : arg))}
          value={this.getValue() ? moment(this.getValue()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : moment(this.props.minDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
          tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
          min={this.props.minDate || null}
          max={this.props.maxDate || null}
        />
      );
    } else {
      element = (
        <DatePicker
          {...this.props}
          name={this.props.name}
          onChange={this.changeValue}
          selected={this.getValue() || this.props.selected}
          startDate={this.props.startDate || null}
          endDate={this.props.endDate || null}
          minDate={this.props.minDate || null}
          tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
          placeholderText={this.props.placeholder}
          ref={this.props.elRef}
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          showYearDropdown={this.props.showYearDropdown}
          locale={this.lang}
        />
      );
    }
    break;
}
```

This loads a react date picker on my landing page.

Since it's been used a lot, I'd like to make it more user-friendly by auto opening the datepicker when the page loads.
I've been searching a lot but I have not found an easy, direct approach to this.

I found this topic (https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/276) but since I'm a bit new to Javascript and React, I need a bit more explanations on how to implement this code in mine, so it would be awesome if anyone could explain to me where exactly I should put my code to implement this function

Thanks a lot everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the autofocus property, since the DatePicker opens OnFocus

```
<input type="text" name="inputname" autofocus>
```

should work :)

for your code:

```
 element = (
    <input
      type='date'
      id={this.props.id}
      name={this.props.name}
      onChange={arg => this.changeValue(moment(arg && arg.currentTarget ? arg.currentTarget.value : arg))}
      onBlur={arg => this.blurValue(moment(arg && arg.currentTarget ? arg.currentTarget.value : arg))}
      value={this.getValue() ? moment(this.getValue()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : moment(this.props.minDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
      tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
      min={this.props.minDate || null}
      max={this.props.maxDate || null}
      autofocus
    />
  );
```

Comment: Editing my answer : after adding your code to mine, i don't see any change unfortunately; adding the 'name' code makes grunt/browserify bug. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to my problem.
The react-datepicker version I had was 0.29.0
Moving it to 0.30.0 (by changing the log in the package.json and running npm install) allowed me to use the new prop autoFocus directly in the datepicker

Here is the code for the 0.30.0 release https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/releases/tag/v0.30.0

Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `open` prop can help anyone. I tried using autoFocus but it didn't work but `open` prop did

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1179#issuecomment-694880947